# How to use Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin to create microservices in Google App Engine?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, microservices, google-plugin-eclipse, google-cloud-tools

As I upgraded my Eclipse to Neon 2 (Eclipse 4.6.2), as "Google Plugin for Eclipse" no longer support, so I switch to Google's "Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin" (https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart)

Last time that is easy to use "Google Plugin for Eclipse" to create multiple modules (known as microservices).  I just need create an "Enterprise Application Project" using GAE as runtime and then create "Dynamic Web Project" and tie to that Enterprise App.

However in this "Cloud Tools for Eclipse", when I choose new Enterprise App, Google App Engine is not an option in runtime selection.

Any help on how to use "Cloud Tools for Eclipse" to create microservices for GAE?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend you don't use, it's better use only [gcloud command-line-tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) to do all tasks that you need (in my view).

Comment: I still prefer to use Eclipse Plugin, after all UI is much simple than command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Cloud SDK on which the new Cloud Tools for Eclipse depends does not support the EAR format. For the moment, you'll need to create individual Eclipse projects for each separate service, and deploy them individually.

We do need to beef up our multi-module support. Though that's not going to happen tomorrow, let me see what I can do about moving it up the stack.

Comment: Thanks mate

So, for multi-module (microservices) I need to use back "Google Plugin for Eclipse" instead of  "Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin".

Hopefully in near future "Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin" will eventually support that function.